# Allowing POST via .htaccess to only one PHP file

Tags: php, ajax, .htaccess, joomla

I work on a Joomla CMS environment, and to keep it safe, I use a very restrictive .htaccess file ([Reference](http://docs.joomla.org/Htaccess_examples_(security))). I want to make an Ajax call to a PHP page like such:

```
...
$.post("http://mywebsite.com/includes/myfile.php", { var: var, var2: var2 },  
...
```

However, these restrictions don't allow me to POST the data to my PHP file, and I get back a 403 (Forbidden) error.

How can I allow a single PHP file to receive POST data, or how can I allow POST data to be sent to a single PHP file?

I've tried the below lines, but they don't work.

```
RewriteRule ^includes/myfile\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_METHOD} !POST
```

Comment: Legit question: How on earth is rejecting POSTS going to make your page more secure?

Answer (score 0):

I've use this line on my htaccess:

```
RewriteRule ^(includes/myphpfile\.php) $1 [L]
```

and it works.